# Qt accessibility plugins

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I use to work with glfw and glew and I want to switch to Qt to create an opengl context (so to replace glfw), but keep using glew and raw opengl functions afterwards.

I have an issue with the creation of the opengl context : my window is transparent and I get this message

```
 Problem creating accessible interface for:  mainWindow(0x160e410) 
 Make sure to deploy Qt with accessibility plugins.
```

I found on this forum that I need to add to my .pro file

```
 QTPLUGIN += qtaccessiblewidgets
```

so I did and nothing changed. They mentionned adding : Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qtaccessiblewidgets) in my main.cpp but when I do I get the compilation error :

```
 expected constructor, destructor or type convertion before '(' token
```

so I guess I used it wrong.

Here are my very simple files. I explected to have compatibility issues between QOpenGLContext and glew, but no an "accessibility" problem...

main.cpp

```
 #include <GL/glew.h> // include GLEW and new version of GL on Windows
 #include <QDebug>

 #include "mainwindow.h"

 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QGuiApplication>
 #include <QOpenGLContext>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv) ;

float windowWidth = 640;
float windowHeight = 480;
mainWindow* win = new mainWindow(NULL,windowWidth, windowHeight);

win->show();

return app.exec() ; 

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
 #include "GL/glew.h"
 #include <QOpenGLContext>
 #include <QWindow>
 #include <QDebug>


class mainWindow : public QWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

mainWindow();
mainWindow(QWindow *parent = 0, float windowWidth = 600, float windowHeight = 400);

~mainWindow();

private:

QOpenGLContext *m_context;

};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"

 mainWindow::mainWindow(QWindow *parent, float windowWidth, float windowHeight): QWindow(parent), m_context(0)
 {
setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);
resize(QSize(windowWidth, windowHeight));
if (!m_context) {
    m_context = new QOpenGLContext(this);
    m_context->create() ;
}
m_context->makeCurrent(this) ;

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (!glewInit ()) {
    fprintf (stderr, "failed glew init\n");
}

//m_context->doneCurrent();
glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
glDepthFunc (GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

glFrontFace(GL_CCW) ;
}
```

On another forum someone had the same issue I have, and they said to copy the plugins folders "imageFormat" and "accessible" to the build folder, so I tried but I only found the imageFormat one, not "accessible" folder on my computer. 
I really dont know what to try next.

Comment: Which OS? Which Qt version?

Comment: Ubuntu and Qt 5.6.1